# Animate multiple controls using a trigger in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, animation, triggers, maui

I am using a separate namespace for triggers to not break MVVM here. When the primary button below is clicked I want to animate said button. So far so good, but I also want to animate one or more other controls on the page at the same time. In this case the `x:Name="AnotherButton"` button, but it could be any element with a name.

How do I trigger an animation for multiple controls in .NET MAUI?

**View**

```
<ContentPage xmlns:triggers="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Triggers">

    ...

    <Button Text="Click this button"
            Command="{Binding ShowOptionsCommand}"
            Opacity="1">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowOptions}" 
                         TargetType="Button" 
                         Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <triggers:ShowOptionsTrigger ShowOptions="True"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <triggers:ShowOptionsTrigger ShowOptions="False"/>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

    <Button Text="Another button"
            x:Name="AnotherButton"/>

    ...

</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private bool showOptions = false;
public bool ShowOptions
{
    get => showOptions;
    set => SetProperty(ref showOptions, value);
}

public Command ShowOptionsCommand { get; private set; }

public OptionsViewModel()
{
    ShowOptionsCommand = new Command(() => ShowOptions = !ShowOptions);
}
```

**Trigger**
I can only animate `sender` here. How do I animate different controls at the same time? This trigger action is in a separate file in a "triggers" folder in my project. So this is not in my ViewModel!

```
namespace MauiApp1.Triggers;

public class ShowOptionsTrigger : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public bool ShowOptions { get; set; }

    protected override async void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
        if (ShowOptions)
            await sender.FadeTo(0.0, 250);
        else
            await sender.FadeTo(1.0, 250);

        // I am trying to also animate AnotherButton like so:
        AnotherButton.FadeTo(1.0, 250);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a solution that goes on your way, but imo it's ok to place things like animations in code-behind, because they're View stuff. So you could simply handle the Button `Clicked` event and get access to all controls you need in code-behind.

Comment: @RiccardoMinato If that is the only way I'm probably fine with that. Though I hope to find a way to do this the MVVM way, so if anyone has a solution it is more than welcome!

Comment: If you are going to animate something on the View, you can do it in the cs file that does not break any MVVM principles

Comment: @FreakyAli Thanks, but besides events how does that work with triggers on a data change in the ViewModel / DataTriggers?

Comment: What I am trying to say is you should not be doing this with your ViewModel, your ViewModel should not be aware of the animations taking place, if you want to use triggers anyway I can take a look

Comment: There's DataTriggers in XAML that trigger on the change of a property in the ViewModel. The actual trigger action animation is in a separate file, in folder named "Triggers" in my case.

Comment: So why are you not applying it to the Views you need it on, if you need it on 10 elements you need to manually add it those 10 elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256793/discussion-between-freakyali-and-dpc).

Comment: Imagine you had 20 controls that needed to be animated, to animate them all you need to add trigger to them all

Comment: Did that mean when a button animates, other controls also get notified?  So  have you tried using a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: Not necessarily notified but simply animated. For example a floating action button that fades out on click, while a tiny menu fades in. Using triggers I can fade out the floating action button when clicked, but I can't fade in the menu. Also, I'm looking for a solution that works without events (e.g. a DataTrigger). I kind of expected triggers to be able to handle multiple other elements as well for slightly more complex animations, but as it seems this is not possible the way I expected it to work.

Comment: I think it's hard to do it. If you want to animate other controls, you should also add ```DataTrigger``` to those controls.  And use data bindings to control the triggers

Comment: I think I'll use multiple triggers for each control then, as FreakyAli also mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Feel free to post an answer below if you have solved your question.